# Effective sample size of jags output versus as.mcmc output

Tags: difference, bayesian, markov-chains, mcmc, jags

I think I do not quite understand jags and as.mcmc functions output. I would like to calculate the effective sample size of the parameters of interest. I have a jags object "jags1" and an mcmc object created from the "jags1" object. When I use the effectiveSize function from coda, I get totally different results and I am confused. Which one should I trust? Why are effectiveSize(jags1) and effectiveSize(jags2) different?
So for example I have:

```
jags1 <- jags(data, model=rats, n.iter=10000, n.burnin=5000, 
n.chain=3,parameters=pars,set.seed(123)))

effectiveSize(jags1)

jags2=as.mcmc(jags1)

effectiveSize(jags2)
```

Comment: I had a similar question regarding ESS.  Maybe my self-answered question on stack exchange helps elaborate? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429470/what-is-the-correct-effective-sample-size-ess-calculation/441628#441628